# What happens if user uses Android version above targeted version?

Tags: android, backwards-compatibility

If I target my Android app for version `x`, will it have any problems if the user uses an Android version above `x`?

What will I have to watch out for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's should work.

> Updates to the framework API are designed so that the new API remains
>   compatible with earlier versions of the API. That is, most changes in
>   the API are additive and introduce new or replacement functionality.
>   As parts of the API are upgraded, the older replaced parts are
>   deprecated but are not removed, so that existing applications can
>   still use them. In a very small number of cases, parts of the API may
>   be modified or removed, although typically such changes are only
>   needed to ensure API robustness and application or system security.
>   All other API parts from earlier revisions are carried forward without
>   modification.

Take a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes! It should work on upper versions of the sdk without error. But you should carefully read the release notes